# Yodlee Rest APIs and all possible responses

Tags: yodlee

I am looking for a more detailed list of possible API responses when using Yodlee's REST API.  Think of it as an XSD response but for a JSON string.  I want to know if there are possible data elements that are not listed Yodlee's JSON response examples.

The only info I can really find so far is [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference).

When I review these examples, it appears that the example JSON responses do not fully describe every field.

Here is part of the **getItemSummaryForItem1** JSON example for maturityDate element

```
"maturityDate":{

},
```

It looks like there is an array, but the possible data elements for that maturityDate array are undeclared.  Then later on maturityDate is shown to be:

```
"maturityDate":{
    "date":"0014-02-01T00:00:00-0800",
    "localFormat":"dd/MM/yyyy"
},
```

And then in another example from getUserTransactionCategories

```
{
  "categoryId":31,
  "categoryName":"Retirement Income",
  "transactionCategoryTypeId":2,
  "isBudgetable":1,
  "localizedCategoryName":"Retirement Income",
  "isHidden":false,
  "categoryLevelId":3
},
```

Based on that I would think all possible data elements are there.
But then there is another one which introduces the childCategory data element

```
{
  "categoryId":2,
  "categoryName":"Automotive Expenses",
  "isDeleted":0,
  "transactionCategoryTypeId":4,
  "isBudgetable":1,
  "localizedCategoryName":"Automotive Expenses",
  "isHidden":false,
  "categoryLevelId":3,
  "childCategory":[
     {
        "categoryId":5641,
        "categoryName":"1_SubCategory1",
        "categoryDescription":"Subcategory desc1",
        "isDeleted":0,
        "isBudgetable":0,
        "localizedCategoryName":"1_SubCategory1",
        "isHidden":false,
        "parentCategoryId":2,
        "categoryLevelId":4
     }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yodlee team is working on to get this details documented, this is a time taking process and will be soon available over their portal. Meanwhile, is there any specific field or API response for which you are looking to get all the child elements which will help you out without blocking your integration?

Comment: Thank you very much for this feedback.  The field I was looking for would be for **Average Monthly Balance** preferably at an account summary level.

Comment: As of now, Yodlee doesn't support any field which will give you this value.